# Unable to print data

Tags: printing, printers, barcode-printing, honeywell

I'm using Honeywell PC42t-203-FP bar code printer. I have installed all related drivers. I'm working in Linux. I have added the printer by using localhost:631. But whenever I try 'Print Test Page' from properties of the printer, it prints nothing. I have checked Job attributes of the printer.

[Here is the snapshot of job attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5cyE.png)

I don't know what is the problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can "talk" to the printer directly on TCP port 9100, and send Fingerprint commands to test if all is working. "PF" and enter should eject one label. (I assumed that you printer is networked).

Answer (score 0):

The printer undersatnds FingerPrint command language. I fear there is no linux driver that translates the graphical test page to FingerPrint commands. FingerPrint is a Basic like language.

Normaly you either write an app that writes FingerPrint commands to the printer (PASSTHRU). or you use a Label tool that supports FingerPrint output.

There is a doc about similar printers and there Linux setup: https://www.intermec.com/public-files/technology-briefs/en/CUPS-Printing-In-Linux-UNIX-For-Intermec-Printers-Tech-Brief.pdf